# Formatear una cadena o numero usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, formato

Tengo una aplicacion que consume una `API`. No tengo control sobre esa `API`, solo puedo consumirla.
La `API` retorna en formato `JSON` un nombre, latitud y longitud.

El problema es que por un problema, la latitud y la longitud la devuelve en un formato incorrecto:

> [{"Name":"River
>   Side","Latitude":-2524544568.0,"Longitude":-5758220052.0}]

Obviamente, necesito que Lat y Long tengan el siguiente formato:

> -25.245445680 y -57.582200520

Una vez que parsee el `JSON`, y tengo cada dato en una variable, como puedo formatear la latitud y la longitud usando `Javascript` para que queden con el formato correcto?

Probe `toFixed`, pero redondea el numero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No me queda claro cuáles son las alternativas que devuelve la API, pero, por lo que deduzco, no funcionaría con sacar todos los puntos y luego agregar un punto luego de dos dígitos desde la derecha (considerando que puede o no haber un signo)?

Es decir:

```
-2524544568.0 => -25245445680 => -25.245445680
```

En código:

```
var num = "-2524544568.0";
var res = num.toString().replace(".", "");
var pos = 2;
if(res[0] = '-'){
    pos = 3;
}
res = res.slice(0,pos) + "." + res.slice(pos);
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = res;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v4ks23u9/

Comment: Creo que faltaría un parseFloat para que `res` sea numérico

Comment: Claro, depende de cómo necesite el dato final. Tampoco está claro si siempre van a ser dos cifras enteras, ya que la longitud llega a 180º. O, si en el caso de 1º, viene informado como 01. Creo que hay mucho que ajustar, sólo pretendí dar una idea. Gracias por el comentario igual!

Comment: Excelente Amenadiel. Funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Malvarez. Asi es, muy buena tu observacion, pero en mi caso, siempre la parte entera sera de dos dígitos, es decir latitud -25.etc y longitud  -57.etc. Esta funciona no funcionaria con menos de dos dígitos, pero este no es el caso. Para este, funciona muy bien. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que esté solucionado el caso @GuillermoAcosta. No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así no queda flotando como que tu problema continúa y alguien más intenta ayudarte. No es obligatorio, pero suele ser una buena idea. Para más información: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Saludos!

Comment: Hola marlvarez. Aceptada! Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Creo que te bastaría con multiplicar la latitud y longitud por 0.00000001.

Comment: Hola Jose, pasa que no todas las longitudes y latitudes tienen la misma cantidad de dígitos decimal. Estamos tratando de encontrar una forma que tome la parte entera de lo recibido y que agregue un punto a dos dígitos desde la izquierda, y que respete el signo.

Comment: Parece que la API te devuelve 10 números para cada latitud y longitud y deduzco que devolvería 11 si fuera la longitud mayor que 100 o menor que -100, si no es así añade más datos a la pregunta, por lo contrario esta respuesta es correcta.

Comment: Es más estoy seguro de que lo que te devuelve es ggmmss.ss y no sería correcto pasarlo a decimal directamente.

Comment: Hola Jose. La API deberia devolver las coordenadas en Grados Decimales, no en GMS. Es una falla en la API que los devuelva con el punto decimal mal colocado. La solucion de malvarez resuelve el problema. Gracias.